# Prepareforsegue set label

Tags: objective-c, label, uistoryboardsegue

I have a prepareforsegue method that takes a picture and shows it on a different viewcontroller. So I need to set a label on the secondviewcontroller at the same time that the pictures is showing, later I'll do a random word generator on that label but right now I just need to set the label. I tried putting it inside the prepareforsegue method but it gives me an error. Here's all my code:

```
//ViewController.m   

     -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if([segue.identifier  isEqualToString:@"CameraSegue"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LibrarySegue"])
        {

            UIImagePickerController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
            controller.sourceType = [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LibrarySegue"] ?  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary : UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            controller.delegate = self;


        }
        else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowImageViewController"]){

            UIImage *image = (UIImage*)sender;
            ShowImageViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            viewController.pickedImage = image;

            UILabel *label = (UILabel *) sender;
            ShowImageViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
            vc.cap = label;
           //I tried to set the label here
            label.text = @"Hello";

        }
    }

    -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            picker.delegate = nil;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowImageViewController" sender:image];
        }];
    }

//SeconViewController.h
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *pickedImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pickedImageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *cap;

//SecondViewController.m

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.pickedImageView.image = self.pickedImage;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get? you declare two `ShowImageViewController` instances `viewController` and `vc` one of them is enough , put this line `label.text = @"Hello";` before `vc.cap = label;`

Comment: It was SIGABRT error, it didn't work either.. I tried what John said and now there's no error but still not showing the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're casting the `sender` to two very different things.

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage*)sender;
ShowImageViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
viewController.pickedImage = image;

UILabel *label = (UILabel *) sender;
ShowImageViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
vc.cap = label;
label.text = @"Hello";
```

You cannot cast a UIImage to a UILabel and expect things to go smoothly. In `prepareForSegue`, you send along an image, not a label.

Can you just change the bottom four lines to:

```
viewController.cap.text = @"Hello";
```

In this case, another option would be to define a new property in `ShowImageViewController` as you did for the image.

```
//SecondViewController.h
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *pickedImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *pickedImageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *cap;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString pickedLabel; //New property

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.pickedImageView.image = self.pickedImage;
    self.cap.text = self.pickedLabel;
}
```

And then in `prepareForSegue`

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage*)sender;
ShowImageViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
viewController.pickedImage = image;
viewController.pickedLabel = @"Hello";
```

Comment: I just tried it, and it didn't give me the error but it didn't show the label.. any ideas? Is there other way to do it?

Comment: Is `cap` or `cap.text` being set in any view event handlers for `ShowImageViewController`? i.e. are you initializing `cap` in `viewDidLoad`? And does the label show up if you set it in `ShowImageViewController` itself?

Comment: It may be preferable to create a property (NSString) within `ShowImageViewController` that gets assigned to the label in one of these handlers and set that property, rather than the IBOutlet, in `prepareForSegue`. IBOutlet connections seem to by asynchronous with other loading processes (at least in my experiences) so it may be `nil` at that time.